# Как удалить класс последнего элемента и добавить другой класс?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

Всем привет! Как можно удалить класс последнего элемента (:last-child) и добавить новый класс? Допустим в ряд идут 3 .col-6, нужно удалить класс .col-6 у последнего элемента и добавить класс .col-12?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте обойтись без скрипта. Если вы хотите при определении размера экрана поменять размер колонки (вдруг) почитайте про явное указание блоков при определенном размере. Можно написать класс `col-6 col-sm-12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так?

```js
const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.col-6');
const first = cols[0];
const last = cols[cols.length- 1];

last.className = "col-12";
```

```css
.col-12 {
  width:100%;
  background:purple;
  height:40px;
}
.col-6 {
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">первый
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">второй
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">последний
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер, огромное спасибо! А как указать, что .col-6 будет именно из .row, а не  другие .col-6. То есть в css я бы написал: .row .col-6 {}, чтобы не применялся к другим col-6 на странице?

Comment: @foreigndezigner проста добавьте внутри querySelectorAll('.row .col-6')

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, все работает!

Comment: `const last = document.querySelector('.row:nth-last-of-type(1) .col-6');`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на jQuery

```js
$('.row .col-6:last').removeClass('col-6').addClass('col-12');
```

```css
.col-6:before { content: '.col-6'; }
.col-12:before { content: '.col-12'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Легче всего будет воспользоваться методом `toggleClass()` с jquery. Это будет выглядеть так
`$('.col-6').last().toggleClass('col-6 col-12');`